# Duplicate behavior in .animate callback chains

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, duplicates, jquery-animate

When I want to chain callbacks with .animate() and want to put some line of code in between, that line of code doesn't execute only one time. In this case the console prints 4 times the string "text". How can this be?

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(articles[index]).offset().top }, 500, function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(likeButton).offset().top - 500}, 1000, function(){
    console.log("text");
  });
});
```

Comment: You are animating `document.documentElement` and `document.body` elements. From jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), callback is called once per element, not once per animation.

Comment: I was doing that because of compatibility issues. But thank you for your response